# Turning Telnet on on Mac OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, telnet

Does Mac OS X Leopard have Telnet client technology? I've seen plenty of stuff around on the internet pertaining to **Snow** Leopard, but not plain old Leopard. I know some people like to use SSH, but I'm only sure that I can use Telnet at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Leopard has telnet built-in, both client and server although the server is stopped for obvious security reasons.

You can run the telnet client by opening up the Terminal app (found in Applications -> Utilities) and then typing "telnet" or the telnet connection command you need.

An alternative way to connect to a telnet server is to open up Terminal app, then from the menu choose "Shell -> New Remote Connection" and enter your telnet server connection details in there. This is for 10.9 but I am pretty sure it was the same in 10.5.

Telnet is inherently insecure and I really wouldn't advise using it across public networks.